# Receiving messages from and sending messages to RabbitMq from WSO2 esb (v. 4.6.0)

Tags: wso2, rabbitmq, wso2-esb

I’m currently investigating the combination of WSO2 esb and RabbitMq and, although I’m getting closer (:-) ), something still goes wrong. I've read this [article](http://kishanthan.wordpress.com/2013/03/26/amqp-transport-for-wso2-esb-based-on-rabbitmq-java-client/).
The feature is installed, receiver and sender configured. I see the queue1 and exchange1 automaticly being created in RabbitMq. But everytime I want to test the configuration by sending a message to queue1 in the RabbitMq management site I get following error:

——–

```
[2013-06-07 16:37:00,230] INFO – ProxyService Successfully created the Axis2 service for Proxy service : AMQPProxy
[2013-06-07 16:37:33,600] ERROR – NativeWorkerPool Uncaught exception java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.getConsumerDelivery(ServiceTaskManager.java:290)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.rabbitmq.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:179)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

———-

Does anybody has an idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have not set the content type and content Encoding when sending the message. Please make sure you set the contentType and contentEncoding in the builder.

```
builder.contentType("text/xml");
builder.contentEncoding("utf-8");
```